# Skydrive 1 way sync possible?

Tags: windows, windows-8, onedrive

I have no external hard disk to backup, so I want to use my skydrive account as my backup source.The problem is, AFAIK skydrive uses 2 way sync: so if someone will hack and get access to my skydrive (live) account and delete something from it, skydrive app will automatically delete these files from my pc too. Is there any way to set sync only 1 way: Backup? I mean sync only from PC to Web not in both directions. Or how to deal with this problem? How to secure files in pc?

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can simply upload the files using the web app. If you don't install the Skydrive app on your pc you won't have 2-way sync.

Remember though that if somebody hacks your account, you will lose your files anyway, even if you have one-way sync. 2-way sync is not the problem, if you want to feel safer, use a stronger password to protect your Live account.

Answer (score 0):

The latest SkyDrive client allows selective sync, so that not all files are downloaded again.

http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/archive/2012/11/15/skydrive-usage-has-doubled-in-the-last-6-months-now-you-can-select-what-to-sync.aspx

So you can now store some backups on SkyDrive without having them again synced on your drive.